# aws lambda timeout when index into elasticsearch

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I am trying a simple lambda function to index event into elasticsearch.

My elasticsearch is behind VPC, so is my lambda function. subnet and security group are all identical.
I am sure that

My ES client is like follows:

```
es_host = 'vpc-somethingsomething.eu-west-1.es.amazonaws.com'
es = Elasticsearch(
        hosts=[{'host': es_host, 'port': 443}],
        http_auth=awsauth,
        use_ssl=True,
        verify_certs=True,
        connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection
    )
```

And I am sure that ES host is correct this way, otherwise I get 'Failed to establish a new connection' error.

```
# key = parsing_key_from_event()
print("the record being indexed: ", body)
res = es.index(index='my-index-name', id=key, body=body)
print("index response: ", res)
```

I see the first print with proper dict that represents my index model. I can't get to see the last print because es.index does timeout. index's name and key are censored but correct in real setup.

The role that I assign to lambda function has god-mode on for elasticsearch and has suggested permits for EC2.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                "dynamodb:*",
                "es:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Anyone knows why es.index timeout given all these informations?

Comment: "subnet and security group are all identical." Being in the same security group has no meaning unless you also create a rule in the security group to allow access from other members of the same security group. Please include your actual security group configuration in your question.

Comment: you are right! Adding an inbound rule for the same security group solved it. thanks for the  comment!